# Collectd plugin seems to not start

Tags: python, syslog, collectd

The problem is I don't see expected output in the syslog file. I wrote a Python plugin located at "/home/my/collectd/pyPlugin.py". The Collectd configuration in "/etc/collectd/collectd.conf" (Python plugin is enabled with globals true) has this block:

```
<Plugin python>
    ModulePath "/home/my/collectd/"
    LogTraces true
    Interactive false
    Import pyPlugin

    <Module pyPlugin>
        Test "arg1" "arg2"
    </Module>
</Plugin>
```

The plugin is quite simple:

```
import collectd

def configer(confObj):
    collectd.info('config called')

def init_fun():
    collectd.info('my py module init called')

def reader(input_data=None):
    collectd.info('my py read called')

def writer(input_data=None)
    collectd.info('my py write called')


collectd.register_config(configer)
collectd.register_init(init_fun)
collectd.register_read(reader)
collectd.register_write(writer)
```

When I look in "/var/log/syslog" I don't see any of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the top of your collectd.conf file: `LoadPlugin "syslog"`

From the [FAQ](http://collectd.org/faq.shtml#faq%3adiagnostic_output):

> In order to get any output at all, you need to load a log plugin. The
>   two main log plugins are the LogFile and SysLog plugins. We recommend
>   that loading one of those plugins is the first thing you do in your
>   config file, i.e. put the LoadPlugin line at the very top. If no log
>   plugin is loaded, collectd will write to STDERR. After the daemon has
>   forked to the background, you won't be able to see this output
>   anymore, though.

The syslog plugin will show the `info` level by default. Also to confirm that Collectd is running look at a process list or `/etc/init.d/collectd status`.